# $f_n\to f$ weakly in $L^p\implies f\in L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> Suppose that $1<p<\infty,\ f,\ f_n\in L^p([0,1]),\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ ||f_n||_{L^p}\leq 1$ for all $n$.  $f_n\to f$ a.e.
>   Show that $f_n\to f$ weakly and $||f||_{L^p}\leq 1$.

Attempt:
If $f_n\not\to f$ weakly, then there is some subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$, $\epsilon> 0$, $g\in L^q$ such that $|\int (f_{n_k}-f)g|\geq \epsilon$

By Alaoglu's theorem, the closed ball in $L^p$ is weakly compact, so there is some subsequence $\{f_{n_{k\ell}}\}$ that converges to $f$ weakly, which is a contradiction.
However, how would I justify that the sequence converges to $f$ and not something else? Is a.e. convergence sufficient?

For the second part, $1\geq \lim_n|\int f_n g| = |\int fg|$, and taking the $\sup$ over $g\in L^q,\ ||g||_q=1$ gives us $||f||_p\leq 1$

I think I have solved most of the problem, but there's are parts that I am unconvinced about.

Comment: What does $\text{a.e.}$ mean? Sorry if I am amateur at this. I know that i.e. $=$ Id est but are they related?

Comment: a.e. means 'almost everywhere'. It means the property holds except in a set of measure $0$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri thanks for telling me :)

Comment: I have used uniform integrability in my answer. Reference: Theorem 16.13 of Billinglsey's Probability and measure. If you want to know how to prove uniform integrability using boundedness of $L^{p}$ norms please let me know.

Comment: Can you give a proof sketch? This is something I have not encountered before.

Comment: let $m$  denote Lebesgue measure. $m\{|f_n| >T\} \leq \frac 1 {T^{p}} \int_{\{|f_n|>T\}} |f_n|^{p} dm \leq \frac 1 {T^{p}} \int |f_n|^{p} dm   \leq \frac 1 {T^{p}} <\epsilon$ if $T$ is large enough. Next, $\int_{\{|f_n|>T\}} |f_n|^{p} \leq (\int |f_n|^{p})^{1/p} (m\{|f_n| >T\})^{1/q}$ by Holder's inequality, $q$ being $\frac p {p-1}$. Hence   $\int_{\{|f_n|>T\}} |f_n|^{p} < \epsilon$ for all $n$. This is the definition of uniform integrability. Now just apply the theorem from Billingsley's book.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333361/suppose-mu-is-a-finite-measure-and-sup-n-int-f-n1-epsilon-d-mu-in), [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392745/assume-that-f-n-to-f-in-measure-and-sup-n-f-n-lpe-infty-for-some) and [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312525/prove-that-if-f-n-converges-to-f-pointwise-a-e-then-f-n-converges-to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable and $f_n \to f$ a.e. so $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$. Hence $\int_A f_n \to \int_A f$. If $f_n \to g$ weakly where $g \in L^{q}$ then $\int_A f_n \to \int_A g$. This gives $\int_A f=\int_A g$ for all $A$, so $f=g$ a.e.. For the second part you can simply use Fatou's Lemma: $\int |f|^{p} \leq \liminf \int |f_n|^{p} \leq 1$.